# Java JButton not updating

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a JButton that when I call setText(), the text does not update. But as soon as I hover over the button, it updates. How can I fix this so that when I call setText(), the button updates? I will just post the methods that the EDT takes to get to it. It goes in order :)

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {//This is a differn't event. This is not executed by clicking on the same button. It's a differn't one.
            click(new Point(e.getX() + gridScrollPaneViewport.getViewPosition().x, e.getY() + gridScrollPaneViewport.getViewPosition().y));
        }

public void click(Point point) {
                map.selectPlot((PlotGUI) map.getComponentAt(point));
            }
public void selectPlot(PlotGUI plot) {
        ChickenTycoon.getInstance().getScreen().getPlayingScreen().sideBar
                .setPlot(plot);
        selectedPlot = plot;
    }

public void setPlot(PlotGUI plot) {
        title.setText(plot.getName() + plot.getX() + plot.getY());
        for (Component comp : stuffPanel.getComponents()) {
            stuffPanel.remove(comp);
        }
        for (Component comp : plot.getComponentList()) {
            stuffPanel.add(comp);
        }
        update();
    }

public void update() {
        if (ChickenTycoon.getInstance().getScreen().getPlayingScreen().map
                .getSelectedPlot() != null) {
            ChickenTycoon.getInstance().getScreen().getPlayingScreen().map
                    .getSelectedPlot().update();
        }
    }

public void update() {
        Log.m("Updating LandGUI");
        ((CButton) componentList[0]).setText("Buy for $ "//I know I am casting this to a CButton, it's my custom version of JButton. I tried it with a JButton and the same thing happens.
                + ((Land) parentPlot).getPurchasePrice());
    }
```

CButton.java

```
package gui;

import game.GameConfiguration;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import chicken.GlobalConfiguration;

public class CButton extends JButton implements ComponentListener {
    protected static final int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
    private static final Font font = GlobalConfiguration.font;
    private static final Insets INSETS_MARGIN = new Insets(2, 5, 2, 5);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected Area m_areaDraw = null;
    private Area m_areaFill = null;

    private double m_dHeightDraw = 0d;
    private double m_dHeightFill = 0d;
    private double m_dWidthDraw = 0d;

    private double m_dWidthFill = 0d;
    private int m_nMinHeight = 0;
    private int m_nMinWidth = 0;

    private int m_nStringHeightMax = 0;
    private int m_nStringWidthMax = 0;
    private RoundRectangle2D m_rrect2dDraw = null;
    private RoundRectangle2D m_rrect2dFill = null;
    private Shape m_shape = null;

    public CButton(String strLabel) {
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setMargin(CButton.INSETS_MARGIN);
        setFocusPainted(false);
        addComponentListener(this);
        setFont(CButton.font);
        setText(strLabel);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    // Needed if we want this button to resize
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        m_shape = new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getBounds().width,
                getBounds().height);
        m_dWidthFill = (double) getBounds().width - 1;
        m_dHeightFill = (double) getBounds().height - 1;
        m_dWidthDraw = ((double) getBounds().width - 1)
                - (CButton.BORDER_WIDTH - 1);
        m_dHeightDraw = ((double) getBounds().height - 1)
                - (CButton.BORDER_WIDTH - 1);
        setShape();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(int nX, int nY) {
        if ((null == m_shape) || m_shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
            m_shape = new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, this.getBounds().width,
                    this.getBounds().height);
        }
        return m_shape.contains(nX, nY);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHints(hints);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        Stroke strokeOld = g2.getStroke();
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(CButton.BORDER_WIDTH,
                BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
        g2.draw(m_areaDraw);

        if (getModel().isRollover()) {
            g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g2.draw(m_areaDraw);
        }
        g2.setStroke(strokeOld);
    };

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHints(hints);
        if (getModel().isArmed()) {
            g2.setColor(Color.CYAN.darker());
        } else {
            g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
        g2.fill(m_areaFill);
        super.paintComponent(g2);
    }

    private void setShape() {
        // Area
        double dArcLengthFill = Math.min(m_dWidthFill, m_dHeightFill);
        m_rrect2dFill = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0d, 0d, m_dWidthFill,
                m_dHeightFill, dArcLengthFill, dArcLengthFill);
        // WARNING: arclength and archeight are divided by 2
        // when they get into the roundedrectangle shape
        m_areaFill = new Area(m_rrect2dFill);
        // Border
        double dArcLengthDraw = Math.min(m_dWidthDraw, m_dHeightDraw);
        m_rrect2dDraw = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(
                (CButton.BORDER_WIDTH - 1) / 2, (CButton.BORDER_WIDTH - 1) / 2,
                m_dWidthDraw, m_dHeightDraw, dArcLengthDraw, dArcLengthDraw);
        m_areaDraw = new Area(m_rrect2dDraw);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(final String strText) {
        CButton.super.setText(strText);
        Frame frame = JOptionPane.getRootFrame();
        FontMetrics fm = frame.getFontMetrics(font);
        m_nStringWidthMax = fm.stringWidth(getText());
        m_nStringWidthMax = Math.max(m_nStringWidthMax,
                fm.stringWidth(getText()));
        // WARNING: use getMargin. it refers to dist btwn text and border.
        // Also use getInsets. it refers to the width of the border
        int nWidth = Math.max(m_nMinWidth, m_nStringWidthMax + getMargin().left
                + getInsets().left + getMargin().right + getInsets().right);
        m_nStringHeightMax = fm.getHeight();
        // WARNING: use getMargin. it refers to dist btwn text and border.
        // Also use getInsets. it refers to the width of the border
        int nHeight = Math.max(m_nMinHeight, m_nStringHeightMax
                + getMargin().left + getInsets().left + getMargin().right
                + getInsets().right);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
                nWidth + ((2 * getFont().getSize()) / 5), nHeight
                        + ((2 * getFont().getSize()) / 5)));
        // Set the initial draw and fill dimensions
        setShape();
    }
}
```

Comment: plz show how you code it.

Comment: To fix it, you must fix the bugs in your code. For us to help you, we must ***see*** those bugs. Our powers of seeing code not shown and understand concepts not explained are vastly overrated.

Comment: Let me see if I can unravel all the stuff going on, it's being run from the EDT I know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JLabel does not update when using setText method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578390/jlabel-does-not-update-when-using-settext-method)

Comment: Added the code to the question

Comment: This isn't the same thing happening as JLabel's. When you hover over the button, it repaints. But when I call repaint() after setText, nothing happens.

Comment: I could upload the whole project if you guys want it...

Comment: Plz, show your CButton class and how you initialize it

Comment: I tried it out with JButton and it did the same thing, but I added it anyways :) To initialize the CButton I just say: componentList[0] = new CButton("");

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I needed to add a repaint to the container for the button. Simple as that!

```
button.setText("Some Text");
buttonContainer.repaint();
```